# Entity framework autogenerated table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework one often writes queries such as

```
var orders = from o in context.Orders.Include("Customer")
             where o.OrderDate.HasValue && o.OrderDate.Value.Year == 1997
             orderby o.Freight
             select o;
```

What really makes my stomach churn is the `"Customer"` string argument. I have a hard time believing that EF does not generate table names as constants somewhere. Does anyone know a better approach than to using a string? for the `Include` fetch option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EF 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2dc5ddac-5a96-48b2-878d-b9f49d87569a) has strongly typed version of Include usable for IQueryable, ObjectQuery and DbQuery. Once you add reference to EntityFramework.dll (EF 4.1) you can add using System.Data.Entity and use eager loading with lambda expressions

```
// get Orders with related Customers
var orders = from o in context.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer) ...
```

Edit:

If you don't want to use EF 4.1 check [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx). I already used in my project and I'm happy with it.

Comment: 4.1 is just library. You can still use 4.0 and link the library to get the feature.

Answer (score 1):

IMO GetType might help you other than .edmx file where all the definitions is stored,

```
 context.Orders.Include(CustomerEntity.GetType.Name or full name )
```

Comment: Nope, this is wrong, because navigation property names can be changed.

Comment: it won't have any issue, as edmx mapping takes care of it.

Comment: No, if type of Navigation Property is "Customer" I can change the name in Navigation Property in EDMX to "FirstCustomer" however doing this, everywhere where .Include("Customer") is used, will not be renamed, the problem is with refractoring.

Comment: i guess he turn off features of using navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Include(context.Customers.EntitySet.Name)
```

?

Comment: Unfortuantelly no because Customers is entity set defined in model but `Include` expects name of the property defined in entity. The name can differ from entity set.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Text Template which will allow you to generate the code in addition to EF's default code. You can do this by right click and clicking "Add Code Generation Item".

In this text template, you can create your constants as you need in "CustomerProperties" and create constant name for each navigation property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520

Comment: sounds interesting. I haven't played around with .tt yet, can you please elaborate on what to insert?